# Embed controller in Zend?

Tags: zend-framework

I am using Zend to make a social network. I created a UserController for authentication and a BlogController. When I enter siteurl/user/userid the information of the user is retrived. How can I make the blog controller inside user controller, so when I click the blog button of the user controller the website will direct me to the user's blog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean.  In your view, you can simply put a button with a link in plain html:

```
<a href="siteurl/blog/showblog/userid/#"><button>View Blog</button></a>
```

Of course, you could build your url with the view helper:
First, pass the userid parameter to the view from your controller:

```
$this->view->userid = $this->_getParam('userid');
```

And then in your view script:

```
<a href="<? echo $this->url(array(
'controller'=>'blog',
'action'=>'showblog',
'userid'=>$this->userid));?>"><button>View Blog</button></a>
```